# Printing Large Size, Large Scale Maps

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, cartography

I am trying to print a very large wall map in QGIS, at large scale. I'm getting a memory overflow message. Any ideas of how to get it to work?

I have been able to export at 50dpi but no higher...

And/or what amount of RAM would be necessary?

Comment: What data are you trying to publish? Raster or vector? What is the complexity of your (vector)data? Sources - WMS or other?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, when I try to export to image. 
In my case the solution was the following: 
I exported not to image, but to pdf. This process doesn't need so much RAM (I checked, about 1,5 GB RAM was used). I exported to my B0 size map at 150 dpi (the result was a 8.1 MB large pdf file).

Answer (score 1):

You could break the large map up into tiles, using the atlas generator or a separate print composer for each tile. Export each tile separately at the desired resolution. Then reassemble the tiles in an image editing program.